# What should happen when a flag is deemed valid?

Tags: support, flags

I just flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) as "non-constructive" because, per the definition, it's a question that "will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

The flag was deemed valid. However, the post is still there. I'm not fixated on having this question deleted or anything - but I just wonder why we are expected to flag bad content if nothing happened when it's approved? So is it normal or a bug?

Comment: Just a guess - the question is old and already has 90 answers. The "extended discussion" has already happened, and it is too late to stop that now. A new question looking like that would be a different matter.

Comment: Would be nice to have a close reason "Completed.  This question is complete and does not need more answers.  It is closed also because questions of this type, while once acceptable here, are no longer welcome.  So don't use it as an example of why your question shouldn't have been closed, whiners."  Or something similar.  Maybe a little bit shorter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deletion/closure is the only thing that auto-validates a flag. As such, if the task is actually something along the lines of locking/editing, then it will have to be done separately from the actual dismissal of the flag. Depending on the task, it may be done such that the dismissal is done, *then* the corrective act. As such, in some cases, if you just have the right timing, you may see what looks like a blank dismissal.

---

Perhaps the more pertinent point is that dismissing a flag as valid specifically means that your flag was not noise and had a functional use. It doesn't necessarily mean that the moderator agrees with the action you have suggested to be taken, but you flagged while attempting to enforce what is understood of the rules thus making it valid. The more common case of a non-matching flag that is valid may be if one person suggests one close reason but the moderator selects another one.

The case shown here is also plausible - the moderator sees the flag and deems that you were doing your responsibility in highlighting what you believe to be a problem, but disagreed that the post is not constructive. A moderator still had to investigate the question and make sure everything is in order, so even if the resolution was different, the purpose of the flag (to get moderator attention) was valid.

Comment: When I don't act on a flag, I use a coin flip to decide whether to dismiss valid or invalid. I flip it until it falls tails and then dismiss invalid.

Comment: That's how I handle them. If I can see _why_ someone flagged something the way that they did, but don't see any reason to take the suggested action, I validate the flag. The bulk of my 'dismissed as invalid' flags revolve around the `not an answer` flag reason. This is usually a case of the person auto flagging based on the results of a query, where a few valid (but pattern matching) answers turned up.